# Android error when accesing sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, copy

I have an app published which has a sqlite database, but I'm receiving this error from some users (more than 99% of the users don't get the error) but one or two each day send me this trace:

java.lang.Error: /data/data/(PACKAGENAME)/databases/(FILENAME).sqlite: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is my code:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
  InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME+".sqlite");
  String outFileName = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+ DB_NAME+".sqlite";
  OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int length;
  while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
       myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }
  myOutput.flush();
  myOutput.close();
  myInput.close();
}
```

I'm confused because it works with every smartphone, but on some of them it is not working correctly :(

Comment: Try to look at the exception logs and stack trace to find the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), rather than roll your own package-a-database-in-assets logic.

But, let's pretend for the moment that the city of Los Angeles is being held hostage by some super-villain, where the city will be nuked into oblivion unless you implement your own package-a-database-in-assets code. And, let's further pretend that you like Los Angeles.

In that case, you will want to fix two problems.

First, replace:

```
String outFileName = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+ DB_NAME+".sqlite";
```

with:

```
File outFile=myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME+".sqlite");
outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

This not only gets rid of the string concatenation (where you are making some assumptions), but it also works for secondary user accounts (where your code might not, as the behavior of `getDataDirectory()` is rather undocumented). It is also shorter. The `mkdirs()` call just ensures that this directory exists before continuing.

Second, change:

```
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
```

to:

```
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.getFD().sync();
myOutput.close();
```

This ensures that everything is written to disk before proceeding. `flush()` simply moves bytes out of the VM to the OS, but the OS does its own filesystem-level write caching. `sync()` tells the OS to write everything to disk. If you have C/C++ background, `sync()` calls the POSIX `fsync()` under the covers.

These issues could cause the sort of error that you are getting. There may be other causes, and so I cannot guarantee that these will completely clear things up.

(Also, unless your database is pretty small, I'd increase the `byte[]` a bit, to 8KB or 16KB or so, to boost performance a pinch. However, that's unlikely to be contributing to your error.)

Answer (score 0):

Almost all devices has directory specified as:

> Environment.getDataDirectory() +
>   "/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+ DB_NAME+".sqlite";

But we should check that whether(directory) it is exist or not.
So first check that directory is exist or not and if it does not exist , create directory. Code is as follows:

```
String dir="/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
File file = new File(dir);
if(file.exists()==false){
     //directory does not exist
     boolean result = file.mkdirs();
}else{
    //file is exist
 }
```